# Internet explorer doesn't load my CSS file

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On a site, Internet explorer doesn't load one of my CSS file and I don't know why. Every other browser works fine, except IE. I checked it in the IE developer bar and it shows that it downloads the CSS, but never get parsed. It is not in the list on the CSS tab.

Link to the problematic site: http://xboxlivesport.altervista.org/

Css, which fail to load: http://xboxlivesport.altervista.org/cache/mod_smartslider_theme/408/ae575c4baa80f0688782202ec181ad9b.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE supports a maximum of 32 css file links. You'll need to combine some of them.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer [only supports a limited number of stylesheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The limit is something along the lines of 31 or 32. You have 34 stylesheets in that document.